# How to publish binary executables as homebrew taps for both MacOS and Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, homebrew

I have a CLI tool, written in Rust, which I have successfully compiled and uploaded as my own Homebrew "tap" on GitHub at https://github.com/RandomStudio/homebrew-tether

Installation is as simple as `brew tap randomstudio/tether` followed by `brew install tether`, which is great!

The repo simply contains the formula file and the releases which are `.tar.gz` archives of a single binary - which was compiled for MacOS (Apple Silicon / AARCH64).

I would like the executable to work on Linux systems, too - x86_64 and ARM (Raspberry Pi), installable via homebrew (which supports Linux for the last few years in addition to MacOS).

I have searched through the docs and done plenty of Googling but I cannot figure out how to publish a cross-platform "tap" (or "bottle", since I just want to publish the binaries?).

Are you supposed to...

- Archive a bunch of different binaries for different architectures all in the same `.tar.gz` file?
- Or multiple archives?
- What should the formula `.rb` look like and how would it distinguish between the executable needed for your target architecture?

I can't find this information anywhere.

For reference, the current `./Formula/tether.rb` is very straightforward at the moment:

```
# Documentation: https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook
#                https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Formula
class Tether < Formula
  desc "Tether CLI utilities"
  homepage "https://github.com/RandomStudio/homebrew-tether"
  url "https://github.com/RandomStudio/homebrew-tether/releases/download/v0.2.0/tether.tar.gz"
  sha256 "639a351e33a285ea8a4feb1abfba21499361f00c93eecc573cbf366bbea2d23a"
  version "0.2.0"

  def install
    bin.install "tether"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems to be open-source. Homebrew is designed to compile formula being installed. The file downloaded by your formula should have the source code. Your formula should compile the program and install it. If your formula needs dependencies only for building, mark them as a build only dependency.

To build a bottle you want to install the formula with `brew install --build-bottle tether` and create a bottle in the correct directory using `brew bottle tether` which will also output a dsl to insert into your formula. Do this using the target OS you want to support.

Your will need to modify the dsl outputted before inserting it into your formula.

An example is if your dsl is this:

```
bottle do
  sha256 "4921af80137af9cc3d38fd17c9120da882448a090b0a8a3a19af3199b415bfca" => :yosemite
  sha256 "c71db15326ee9196cd98602e38d0b7fb2b818cdd48eede4ee8eb827d809e09ba" => :mavericks
  sha256 "85cc828a96735bdafcf29eb6291ca91bac846579bcef7308536e0c875d6c81d7" => :mountain_lion
end
```

You need to change it to this:

```
bottle do
  root_url *INSERT BASE URL WHERE BOTTLES STORED HERE*
  sha256 "4921af80137af9cc3d38fd17c9120da882448a090b0a8a3a19af3199b415bfca" => :yosemite
  sha256 "c71db15326ee9196cd98602e38d0b7fb2b818cdd48eede4ee8eb827d809e09ba" => :mavericks
  sha256 "85cc828a96735bdafcf29eb6291ca91bac846579bcef7308536e0c875d6c81d7" => :mountain_lion
end
```

Then you insert it into your formula.

I suggest reading https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles for more info.